# copy looping matrixes into one 3-d matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a list of text files that I would like to load, and then extract rows where they all overlap.  The first column contains years and each data set spans a different chunk of years but they all overlap in the middle.  In the end I would like to have a three dimensional matrix with the overlapping years in one matrix.  My code keeps getting stuck at the line that I have commented out.  I know its incorrect but could anyone tell me why it is incorrect?

```
clear all
name_list =  {'Beijing';'GT';'soi';'naoi';'Sydney_Airport';'Los Angeles';'Paris';'Presque Isle'};
[m,n] = size(name_list);

files = dir('*.txt');
[m,n] = size(files);

for i=1:m
    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
    vals{i} = load(files(i).name);
    matrix = vals{i};
    station = (files(i).name(1:end-4));
    startyear(i) = min(matrix(:,1));
    endyear(i) = max(matrix(:,1));
    allstart = max(startyear);
    allend = min(endyear);
    %matrixnew(i) = matrix(allstart:allend,2:13,i); 
end
```

Comment: Also, when I run this without the '%' I receive the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error message.  I'm trying to learn why that is.

Comment: Are you expecting the matrix variable to have 3 dimensions?  Add size(matrix) before the commented statement to see what it's dimensions are.  Also, you probably need to assign to a cell array (i.e. replace matrixnew(i) with matrixnew{i}).

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

1. Your commented line `%matrixnew(i) = matrix(allstart:allend,2:13,i);` assumes that `matrix` is a 3-d array, but elsewhere you treat it as 2-d (and I believe that `load` always returns a 2-d array). This could be why you are getting the "Index exceeds matrix dimensions" error. Example:

   ```
   >> foo = rand(10,10);
   >> foo(2:10,3:4,2)
   Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
   ```

   Maybe you want `matrix(allstart:allend,2:13)`? But that won't work, because `allstart` contains a *year*, which presumably will not be a valid index for the array (a more likely cause of your error). Using the *index* that contains the smallest value would be closer to being correct, but I think it still won't work.
2. `matrixnew` refers to a single element of an array. You can't assign an array to an element of an array.  grantnz is right that making `matrixnew` a cell array would fix this error, and I guess that in the end you could turn your cell array into 3-d array.

I think you are on the right track, but are missing a few pieces to making this work. One thing to consider is that it looks like you are trying to do everything in a single pass. I don't see how that can work. You need to real *all* files before you can decide which range of years to keep. So do it in multiple passes: first load all data from all files into a cell array, then figure out the range of years, then pull the data from each file for that range of years.